# Returning a reference to an element of a class member container

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, member

Foo behaves like a circular iterator.  Despite me being nervous about it, the code below compiles fine, but creates a run-time error.  I receive the error even if I remove the consts from get_current().  Of course, I can return a pointer and it'll work; however, will I get better security returning a reference?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  void next();
  const int& get_current() const;
private:
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3> arr_;
  unsigned i_;
};

Foo::Foo() : i_(0)
{
  arr_[0] = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(5));
  arr_[1] = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(6));
  arr_[2] = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(7));
}

void Foo::next()
{
  ++i_;
  i_ %= 3;
}

const int& Foo::get_current() const 
{
  return *arr_[i_];
}

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  int* p;

  *p = foo.get_current();
  //do something with p
  std::cout << *p << std::endl;

  foo.next();
  *p = foo.get_current();
  //do something with p
  std::cout << *p << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* p;
```

That's an uninitialised pointer, not pointing to anything. Dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour.

```
*p = foo.get_current();
```

That dereferences the invalid pointer. Boom!

Perhaps you want it to point to the array element

```
p = &foo.get_current();
```

or perhaps you want a copy of the array element

```
int n;
n = foo.get_current();
```

Answer (score 2):

`foo.get_current();` may well be returning a `const` reference, but after that you're attempting to take a *value* copy of that when assigning to `*p`.

Assigning to `*p` is what's causing you trouble as `p` is *uninitialised*. That's *undefined behaviour* and is manifesting itself in your case as a runtime error.

You *could* use code like `const int& p = foo.get_current();` but do be aware that a reference can only be bound once, so you'll have to be careful with scoping.

*Or*, you could use `std::shared_ptr<int>` and make that the return type of `get_current()`, and strip your code entirely of bare pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`*p = ...` You dereference `int* P` without having it properly initialized.

Change your code in main to

```
 int p; // Remove *

 p = foo.get_current();
 //do something with p
 std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

or if you really meant to use a pointer

```
 const int* p;

 p = &foo.get_current();
  // ^ Take the address
```